# forward variables from functionapp (powershell $value) to Application Insights and create action group based on it and send email

Tags: azure, powershell

I have a running Azure Function app (PowerShell) and for business purposes, I need to send informational emails about disk capacity to users. I tried using MS Graph, but since I don't have an Office 365 or Exchange Online license, it doesn't work as intended. Additionally, I don't want to use any third-party solutions like SendGrid.

My idea is to collect all the usage information and contacts into an array per Resource Group (RG) and send it to the RG owner using an Action Group. The Action Group will have different contact emails that will change dynamically in the loop, depending on the RG.  Something like below

```
foreach ($email in $emails) {
$emailReceiver = New-AzActionGroupReceiver  -EmailAddress $email -Name "Admin"
$actionGroup = Set-AzActionGroup -Name "Cost Notification of $rgName" -ShortName "Cost" -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Receiver $actionEmail
```

}

The question is, how can I forward the $value from function app (an array with email contacts where usage is high) to Application Insights and track $value ? or any other ideas how to track $value from functionapp and send email based on $value, are welcome

Comment: does your function app run on powershell? and what does $value contain?also Is it necessary to use Application insights for your requirements?

Comment: function app run on powershell but not needed to use function app and Application insights, but PowerShell must be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve your requirement which worked for me is to use smtp connection. Below is the complete script that helped me get the disk details and send it to the required email.

```
$disk = Get-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName $resourceName
$value = disk.DiskSizeBytes

$emailPassword = "<<Password>>"
$fromEmail = "<<From_Email>>"
$emailCredential = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($fromEmail, $emailPassword)

$smtpServer = "smtp.office365.com"
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$smtp.Port = 587
$smtp.EnableSSl = $true
$smtp.Credentials = $emailCredential

foreach ($email in $emails) {
    $messageObject = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
    $messageObject.IsBodyHtml = $true
    $messageObject.From = $fromEmail
    $messageObject.To.add($email)
    $messageObject.subject = "Sample"
    $messageObject.body = "Disk Usage is " +$value
    $smtp.Send($messageObject)
}
```

Results:

[image]